# Using entity_id in a db_query in views_php (Drupal 7)

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have created the following code in views_php:

```
$userseeking = db_query("SELECT field_seeking_tid FROM {field_data_field_seeking} WHERE entity_id = 6")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userseekingcount = count($userseeking);
return $userseekingcount
```

In the above example, I use a specific value of '6' for entity_id. I receive the expected result from this query.

However, the entity_id needs to be a variable dependent on the logged-in user's Profile ID (connected to their User ID).

I therefore introduce 3 lines to retrieve the PID ($currentpid) from the current user. I have confirmed that these 3 lines return a $currentpid value of 6. When I ammend the db_query to select values where the entity_id = $currentpid, there appears to be a failure, although they should yield the same result - see code below:

```
global $user;
$currentuser = $user->uid;
$currentpid = db_query('SELECT pid FROM {profile} WHERE uid = ' . $currentuser . ' limit 1')->fetchField();

$userseeking = db_query("SELECT field_seeking_tid FROM {field_data_field_seeking} WHERE entity_id = ' . $currentpid . '")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userseekingcount = count($userseeking);
return $userseekingcount
```

Am I misusing how entity_id is referenced in this query?

Thanks for your help!

PS This may not be the cleanest code, so I apologise in advanced! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a misuse of syntax in the above example. In particular it was my use of " and ' when creating $userseeking.

Hopefully others can learn from my rookie error :)

The corrected code is:

```
global $user;
$currentuser = $user->uid;
$currentpid = db_query('SELECT pid FROM {profile} WHERE uid = ' . $currentuser . ' limit 1')->fetchField();

$userseeking = db_query('SELECT field_seeking_tid FROM {field_data_field_seeking} WHERE entity_id = ' . $currentpid . '')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userseekingcount = count($userseeking);
return $userseekingcount
```